# AngularJS : Creating custom filter for decimal points

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to convert below JS code into re-usable AngularJS filter

```
var a = 1.1230000,
    b = a.toFixed(15).replace(/\.?0+$/, "");  // ==> 1.123
```

I have created below code(AngularJS)

```
  angular.module('myApp.filters', []).filter('fixed', [function () {
    return function(input) {
      return input = input.toFixed(15).replace(/\.?0+$/, "");
    };
  }]);
```

and invoked the new filter to module

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['fixed']);
```

**but it displays an Error:** [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%.........

Am I missing anything and I am sorry for any mistake. Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE - Added [JSBIN URL](http://jsbin.com/lulitibi/1/edit)**

Comment: The problem should be in the loading, please check. Cheers.

Comment: I guess you first need to fix your filter code. Your `return input2` statement needs to be inside the block above it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject components that are already part of your module.  myApp.filter('filterToFixed is already in the module myApp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are not inject `filters` module into you `myApp` module. change you code like this it will work for you

```
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['filters']);//inject your filters Module into myApp Module


   angular.module('filters', []).filter('fixed', function () { //change module name as filters
    return function(input) {
      return input.toFixed(15).replace(/0+$/, "");
    };
  });
```

[updated Bin](http://jsbin.com/lulitibi/3/)

**solution2**

based on you code you may change like this.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters']);//inject myApp.filters into your myApp Module.
```

remaining code works like charm...

[jsBin for Solution2](http://jsbin.com/lulitibi/5/)